# Microsoft Office Web App PowerPoint API

Tags: ms-office

Facebook has a nice way to preview powerpoint files.. It goes to a microsoft link, e.g. [link](https://powerpoint.office.live.com/p/PowerPointView.aspx?FBsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdownload%2Ffile_preview.php%3Fid%3D201399386714335%26time%3D1386371663%26metadata&access_token=100000234043560%3AAVLFIlZKlUk8gAswD36-X3WyIsVVf5TkQSf868imzgXo9w&title=MxAgCrProd.ppt). You can browse the presentation etc, all very nice and useful for the user and Facebook.

However, I cannot find any sort of API doing that with microsoft.

I found [this](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-powerpoint/archive/2013/01/10/embedding-presentations-into-your-website-with-the-powerpoint-web-app.aspx) blog post, which is kindof what I want, but its not referencing any API that I can use to produce this programmatically.

I have a website which users can store files (also powerpoint presentations) and would like them to be able to preview it.

Has anyone got any experience with this? Preferably not going through microsoft route (if possible)..

Comment: Hi ! @matejkramny Could you please to explain what is your architecture in backend and your experience in the front-end with this API?

Comment: Hi @inane I was developing a service for meetings and one of the features was a `dropbox`. To open files there, most specifically office files, i was searching for api's etc that can open them. I found a solution through facebook. See how facebook opens word documents etc. You must make a public url for the file and pass that as query parameter to ms office 365

Comment: OK!! great! but if you need to save in determinated extension? for example ppt. and so on..

Comment: Yh thats fine. Office can open that

Comment: So, you save a document for example with the extension ppt in Javascript from a screenshot (for instance) and after open with Office  right?

Comment: Nono i didn't mean that. The file has to be created by microsoft office and uploaded by the user. The api i described is only for opening that in a browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76892/discussion-between-inane-and-matejkramny).

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your Powerpoint is hosted on your website and is publicly accessible, all you have to do is prepend it in this way `http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=<Document Location>`. [Here's an example](http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3a%2f%2fvideo.ch9.ms%2fbuild%2f2011%2fslides%2fTOOL-532T_Sutter.pptx).

This works with ANY office document type including PDF!

#### Reference:

https://blogs.office.com/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/

Comment: Thank you! Since posting my answer, i did find this. Google drive also does this. It is SO hard looking for a solution for this :P

Comment: @matejkramny Glad it worked out for you :) I faced exact same issue but didn't want Google Drive experience as my customers are well acquainted with Microsoft Office. And thankfully, by 2015, MS does have a solution unlike back then when you asked the question in 2013.

Comment: They did have the solution in 2013 :P. It was just undocumented and hard-to-find

Comment: Hey guys, found this solution too and does anyone know how I could send these without opening my folder to be publicly accessed ? Like encoding them in base64 instead of giving the URL to MS ?

Comment: @YannickHelmut I don't think that's possible by any chance because any URL has a max length that would never fit the binary content of a powerpoint file. if you're worried about having the file accessible in the open, you can place the file behind a webserver and that server will server the powerpoint file content after verifying referrer to be MS. OR use Azure Blobs with authentication query string that expire after a few minutes.

Comment: Can we pass basic authorization header to this api? The files I want to preview are behind username/password.